# "Mortgage" - code not passing the last system test [TOPCODER]

Tags: c++, algorithm, search, binary-search

I am trying to solve the [Mortgage](https://arena.topcoder.com/index.html#/u/practiceCode/1362/2248/2427/2/1362) problem on TopCoder. My code works almost good - it passes every system test except the last one, where instead of "1976284585" it returns "1976284584". I tried to solve this problem, I can't do it though. Can you help me?

My source code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>
using namespace std;
class Mortgage{
public:
    int monthlyPayment(int loan, int interest, int term){

    long double lo = 0;
    long double hi = 2000000000;
    long double monthlyPayment;
    long double balance;
    long double ir = interest/10.0/12.0/100.0;
    while((hi-lo)/hi>1e-9){

        balance = loan;
        monthlyPayment = lo+(hi-lo)/2.0;

        for(int i=0;i<term*12;i++){

            balance = balance-monthlyPayment;
            if(balance<=0.0){break;}
            balance = ceil(balance*(1+ir));
        }
        if(balance<=0.0){
            hi=monthlyPayment;
        }else{
            lo=monthlyPayment+1;
        }
    }
    return lo;  
    }
};
```

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of floating point math on a computer. It *will* lead to rounding problems, like the one you seem to have.

Comment: Is there anything I can do to help? It is really annoying :/

Comment: Use *integer* math?

Comment: Use *fixed point* math?